# Clarification on SQL table

Tags: sql, ms-access, vba, ms-access-2010

This is a table that i am going to access.

```
Account | col1 | col2 | col3
.............................
value 1   x1     x2     x3
value 2   x1     x2     x3
```

What i want to do is i want convert this table into this format as i mentioned below,

```
Account | Carrier |  |
........................
value 1    col1    x1
value 1    col2    x2
value 1    col3    x3
```

How do i do this by using select sql. i really appreciate if anyone can help me to solve this problem

Thanks,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do a `SELECT` for each carrier. `UNION ALL` the results together:

```
select Account, 'col1' as carrier, col1 from tablename
union all
select Account, 'col2' as carrier, col2 from tablename
union all
select Account, 'col3' as carrier, col3 from tablename
order by Account, carrier
```

Comment: Thank you very much for helping hand. i really appreciate........!!!!!